# How painless is it to upgrade Symfony applications from 1.1 to 1.2

Tags: php, symfony1, migration

I am currently developing a system on a server running PHP version 5.1.6 thus I am forced to use Symfony 1.1 in the current environment.
I am planning to migrate the application from 1.1 to 1.2 in the somewhat near future and I was wondering if anyone has any experience with this?
I have attempted to migrate a system from 1.0 to 1.1 and that was a major pain in the rear.

How has it been for anyone out there migrating from Symfony 1.1 to 1.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, migration to 1.2 was fairly painless. The upgrade script should do all hard work.

The biggest problem will be migrating to propel 1.3 if you have used 1.2 ( default with symfony 1.0.x and 1.1.x). If you were using propel 1.3 before ( with sfPropelPlugin) or Doctrine there shouldn't be any problems.

Another one will be porting admin generated modules to new admin generator, but in 1.2 the oldones still work for now.

Those listed above are the biggest changes in 1.2.

And I love 1.2 for it has lots of new cool stuff ( REST routing, new admin generator, some minor fixes etc.)

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents is that it all depends on how many forms you have in your application, that was by far the most painful part. Symfony 1.2 has an entirely new form system.

you can always do compac10 = true or whatever ...to make your old code compatible,..

Symfony 1.2 does have many new useful widgets,..and propel 1.3 is a significant improvement, fixed some bugs that I was actually running into.

Answer (score 1):

It should be fairly easy if you didn't use custom SQL queries with Propel (i.e. manual hydratation) as Propel 1.3 switches to PDO.
I migrated an 1.1 app to 1.2 and I had nothing to do except running the automatic upgrade script.